# Web Application Factory In MVC Testing Framework sharing test specific setup?

Tags: c#, .net-core, integration-testing

I'm having a strange issue when using the WebApplicationFactory in the MVC.Testing package for integration testing.
In one test, I'm creating the factory and swapping an injected service for another mocked service using the ConfigureTestServices function, in the other test I'm not doing this. However, I'm finding that each test can end up using the same mock implementation.

// Test 1

```
var mock = new Mock<SomeService>();
mock.Setup(t => t.ProcessJob(It.IsAny<SomeService>()))
    .Throws(new Exception("Exception thrown in unit test"));
    
var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>()
    .WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
    {
        builder.ConfigureTestServices(services =>
        {
            var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(SomeService));
            if (descriptor != null)
                services.Remove(descriptor);

            services.AddScoped<SomeService>(_ => mock.Object);

        });
    });
var client = factory.CreateClient();
var message = BuildMessage();
var response = await client.SendAsync(message);
```

//Test 2

```
var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();
var client = factory.CreateClient();
var message = BuildMessage();
var response = await client.SendAsync(message);
```

I've skipped the assertions as they're irrelevant for this.

So in this example, Test2 ends up using the same mocked "SomeService" object as Test1 does, even though it's never implemented in that instance. The ordering of the test doesn't matter in the sense that Test2 will fail if Test1 runs first and Test1 will fail if Test2 runs first.

I'm confused as to why this would happen. They should be using completely separate containers and therefore be completely isolated.

Any thoughts would be welcome.

EDIT:
Some further investigation shows that a queue is still running in the background as the WebApplicationFactory doesn't seem to get disposed immediately at the end of the tests. Calling .Dispose at the end of the test causes the queue to throw a "can't access disposed object" exception.

Is there a method within the WebApplicationFactory to wait until everything is correctly disposed before ending the test?

Comment: WebApplicationFactory is disposable.  Have you tried, e.g., `using var factory = new WebApplicationFactory<Program>();` to see if this helps the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, calling I IDisposable causes a failure in the WebJobs host for the queue. One or more hosted services failed to stop. (Cannot access a disposed object.)
---- System.ObjectDisposedException : Cannot access a disposed object. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.PrimaryHostCoordinator.StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Hosting\PrimaryHostCoordinator.cs:line 244
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: Are you wanting to do integration tests for your WebJob, or is the WebJob just hosted by your Web application?  If the latter, perhaps you can prevent the WebJob from starting when using WebApplicationFactory.  Our WebJobs and API applications are decoupled and starting one doesn't start the other.  Also, it may be useful to see updated code with your disposal changes.

Comment: The Web Job is an integral part of the application so they’re needed for the integration tests etc. So the webjobs need to start to be able to test properly

Comment: Could you provide an update of your code with the dispose logic?  It sounds like something is being disposed twice, which doesn't seem right.  PrimaryHostCoordinator appears to be the class that coordinates the WebJob host with the Api host.